# Where should I forward an email of a potential hacker?

Tags: gmail

I received the following phishing attempt email:

```
tirossvn tirossvn <tirosssvn@gmail.com> 
13:24 (1 hour ago)

to me 

Dear Account User,
Your Gmail account bain61@gmail.com will no longer receive or send emails after 48 hours!
Review Your Account Now

Review to stop account shunt down.

Best Regards
The Google Accounts
```

Where should I forward it?

Comment: Presumably there's a link in there to some sketchy site.

Comment: Well, a phisher is not exactly a "hacker"...

Answer (score 7):

If you received a phishing message to your Gmail account, you don't need to forward it anywhere. In the normal Gmail client, under the message menu (top right corner of the message, behind the down arrow, next to "Reply"), is an option to "Report phishing". Use that. This way Google will have all of the header information and can investigate accordingly. The message will also be removed from your mailbox.

If you don't have a Gmail account, use the "[report abuse](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/abuse)" form at https://support.google.com/mail/contact/abuse.

See also: [Gmail help: Report messages asking for personal information (phishing)](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/184963)